# A condition for non-degeneracy of an LP

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I heard the following remark in class:

> Let the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and the vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ reflect the equality constraints in a linear program in standard form. Show that if each $m \times n$ submatrix of $[A,b]$ has full rank, then there are no degenerate solutions.

I do not find this to be immediately clear, however. This seems similar to the well-known Linear Algebra theorem that says

> If the rank of $A$ is equal to the rank of $(A\mid b)$ then $(A \mid b)$ is solvable.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's going on in the case $m=2, n=7$. You should have no troble generalizing the result to arbitrary $m,n.$ Let the right-hand side be $\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}$. A degenerate solution is one in which more than $n-m=5$ of the variables are 0. Suppose 6 of the variables are 0. Remove the columns of $A$ corresponding to 5 of the variables. We are left with an equation of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}s&p\\q&r\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}.$$ But one of the remaining variables must be 0, say $x.$ Then Cramer's Rule says that $$x =\det\begin{bmatrix}b_1&p\\b_2&r\end{bmatrix}/\det \begin{bmatrix}s&p\\q&r\end{bmatrix} .$$ The 'full rank' condition means that neither of those detrminants is 0, so $x \ne 0,$ a contradiction. There is a similar contradiction if $y$ is 0. Thus there cannot be a degenerate solution.